# Adding the Extended Menu to a Joomla template

Tags: joomla

I'm creating a website in Joomla! for a friend of mine and I'm having some real trouble getting the menu up and going. All I'm looking for is a simply cascading menu (it will only be 2 levels, VERY simple).

I've got the template going, but there's no menu on it. I've installed the Extended Menu module, but I can't seem to find any documentation on what to do next?

Can anyone point me to a decent tutorial, or give me some tips on what to do next? I'm confident with HTML and CSS, it's just the Joomla! framework which has me lost :(

Cheers,

Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have activate this module you installed to show up in your interface.

In your top menu in Joomla's administration, select "Extensions" > "Module Manager". Search for "Extended Menu Module" or something like that. Check if the module is enabled, if not, enable it by selecting "Yes" in "Enable:" Section.

Now, choose your module "position" from the drop down menu ("left", "user", etc) where you think your module should be.

Check this video tutorial that shows [how to change a module position](http://br.video.yahoo.com/watch/4096338/11052000).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, GmonC. The missing piece of the puzzle for me was adding this line to my index.php:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" ...>
```